# Assigning a DOM object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to assign the DOM object of a webpage to a TypeScript variable.

```
protected DOM_obj : HTMLElement;
DOM_obj = document.defaultView;
```

I however seem to get the following error:

> Type 'Window' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.   Property
>   'accessKey' is missing in type 'Window'.

How would I go about assigning the DOM object of the current window to a TypeScript variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the TypeScript DOM API [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L2672)

`document.defaultView` is of type `Window`.

So your `DOM_obj` needs to be of type `Window` as well:

```
protected DOM_obj : Window;
DOM_obj = document.defaultView;
```

Comment: That makes sense. :)